# Javascript - Bron-Kerbosch, Girvan-Newman algorithm (max cliques/communities in graph)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am searching for an Javascript implementation of the [Bron-Kerbosch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron-Kerbosch_algorithm) or [Girvan-Newman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girvan%E2%80%93Newman_algorithm).

Basically I want to color maximal cliques/communities in an undirected graph.

Sadly, I found only cryptic Python and bloated Java & C++ library code. I need it in plain Javascript code (preferable no bloated JS library or JQuery et al dependencies).

```
// I am using the following data structure
fg_p = []; // Points (Users)
fg_e = []; // Edges

function fgAddUser(uid, name) {
  var t_obj = {};
  t_obj.id = id;
  t_obj.name = name;            
  fg_g[fg_g.length] = t_obj;
}

function fgAddEdge(a, b) {
  var t_obj = {};
  t_obj.a = a; // user A
  t_obj.b = b; // user B
  fg_e[fg_e.length] = t_obj;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to implement them? The algorithms are not that complicated, are they?

Comment: I downloaded various source code implementations though all of them used some language native optimization techniques or language features not present in Javascript. A C code from 1983 used a lot of bit shifting, Java & Python sources relied heavily on vector/dictionary and other native object types, C++ relied on Boost/STL. Nor do I need a heavily parallel version. The wikipedia psydo-code looks easy (though only at the first sight).
I would appreciate a basic implementation in a Javascript or C like language without any optimization.

Comment: You can use arrays for vectors and objects for dictionaries. The pseudocode from WP should be transferable to JS, using arrays for sets (check out [Underscore's source](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html) for some implementations of set methods). Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a module that does the first version of **Bron–Kerbosch** algorithm

```
'use strict';

function graphUtils(){
var methods = {};



methods.allCliques = function(g){
    var cliques=[];
    var p=[];
    g.forEachNode(function(node){
        p.push(node.id);
    });
    var r =[];
    var x=[];

    bronKerbosch(g, r, p, x, cliques);
    return cliques;
};

function bronKerbosch(g, r, p, x, cliques) {
    if (p.length===0 && x.length===0){
        cliques.push(r);
    }

    p.forEach(function(v){
        var tempR= r.splice(0);
        tempR.push(v);
        bronKerbosch(g, tempR, p.filter(function(temp){
            return methods.neighbors(g, v).indexOf(temp)!=-1;
        }), x.filter(function(temp){
            return methods.neighbors(g, v).indexOf(temp)!=-1;
        }), cliques);

        p.splice(p.indexOf(v),1);
        x.push(v);
    });
}

methods.neighbors = function(g, v){
    var neighbors=[];
    g.forEachLinkedNode(v, function(linkedNode){
        neighbors.push(linkedNode.id);
    });
    return neighbors;
};
return methods;
}
module.exports = graphUtils();
```

I didn't try it cause it turns out that I don't need it, tell me if it works or if I need to fix something